# dts-gen ReferenceError: Java is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-definitions

I am trying to generate TypeScript definition file (.d.ts) from JavaScript file (*.js)...It has converted all the files expect on Java Script file which contains the following statement

```
return Java.type('com.test.TestExample').START_ELEMENT
```

Error Message:

ReferenceError: Java is not defined

```
at Function.get ATTRIBUTE [as ATTRIBUTE] (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\uuk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dts-gen\bin\lib\run.js:71:64), <anonymous>:95:27)
at getResult (C:\Users\uuk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dts-gen\bin\lib\index.js:148:47)
at getTopLevelDeclarations (C:\Users\uuk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dts-gen\bin\lib\index.js:124:17)
at Object.generateIdentifierDeclarationFile (C:\Users\uuk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dts-gen\bin\lib\index.js:68:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\uuk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dts-gen\bin\lib\run.js:71:24)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Can you please tell me what is this issue and how to fix this?

Comment: `Java Script` is kinda confusing. I'm not sure if you're talking about the the javascript language, or if you're referring to `.java` files as "Java Script files".

Comment: It is JavaScript file (.js file)...

Comment: Is `Java` defined/imported anywhere in the javascript file?

Comment: Yes...As mentioned, it is defined in 2 places as follows:

return Java.type('com.test.TestExample').START_ELEMENT;

this.xmlStreamReader = new (Java.type('com.test.TestFile'))(streamReader.getInputStream());

Comment: Those are usages, not definitions. It sounds like `Java` isn't imported or declared. I don't know if this is just how `dts-gen` works, but it sounds like a problem.